# How should I create the constraints for these two related tables?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating two tables. The first is the `Invoices` table which tracks all the invoices from my vendors.
The next is the `InvoiceItems` table which tracks all the items from one invoice(Cause there might be more than one item in the invoice). I know I'll need the primary key InvoiceID from the Invoices table as a foreign key in the InvoiceItems table, but given the similar way my textbook tackles the problem versus how other people on here have showed me is a bit different, can you explain if something is being left out or is it just a different coding style.

Here is the way my textbook does it

```
/****** Object:  Table InvoiceLineItems     ******/
CREATE TABLE InvoiceLineItems(
    InvoiceID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceSequence smallint NOT NULL,
    AccountNo int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceLineItemAmount money NOT NULL,
    InvoiceLineItemDescription varchar(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_InvoiceLineItems PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    InvoiceID ASC,
    InvoiceSequence ASC
 ) 
)
GO

/****** Object:  Table Invoices     ******/
CREATE TABLE Invoices(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    CreditTotal money NOT NULL,
    TermsID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDueDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Invoices PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    InvoiceID ASC
 )
)
GO
```

Here's how I did it

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_InvoicesList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    InvoiceID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: Table*****/
CREATE TABLE InvoiceItems(
    InvoiceID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceItem varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ItemPrice money NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_Invoices_InvoiceItems
    FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceID) REFERENCES Invoices(InvoiceID)
)
```

I first notice the textbook creates the dependent table first, because the InvoiceID is the `Invoices` tables primary key, what confuses me is the author writes InvoiceID to be the Primary key constraint for both tables?? So whats refrencing what?

Comment: Simply creating two tables that have a column of the same name does NOT create any actual relationship or constraint. Don't assume. The "book method" does nothing by create primary keys - there is no actual defined relationship. And you did NOT create a primary key for your dependent (InvoiceItems) table - which is generally a serious fault.

Comment: And as I mentioned in your previous question (on the same topic btw), using smalldatetime for a date attribute is generally just plain wrong. Using a type that includes a time component just encourages sloppy data and complicates coding. If you intend to store just a date, then use the DATE datatype.

Comment: The textbook is wrong you have to create invoices before invoiceitems.

Comment: @SMor Sorry I'm just getting into SQL. I'll change the data type. But how then do I create this relationship? How do make the Invoice Items correspond with the InvoiceID from the Invoice tables? Or do I just keep track of it as I hard code in the values